# php 7.x array transformation

Tags: arrays, php-7

```
array:3 [
  0 => {
    +"zoomlevel": 1
    +"metric_cnt_1": 1
  }
  1 => {
    +"zoomlevel": 4
    +"metric_cnt_1": 1
  }
  2 => {
    +"zoomlevel": 6
    +"metric_cnt_1": 2
  }
]
```

Above array is a result of an sql query like:

```
select district_id as zoomlevel, count(*) as metric_cnt_1
from members
group by district;
```

and I want to 'transform' it into:

```
array:3 [
  1 => 1,
  4 => 1,
  6 => 2
]
```

Does php has any array function which can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [@mark-baker's answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891045/php-7-x-array-transformation/50900601#50900601). It's better than this one (other than perhaps the PDO bit at the bottom).

---

There's no real trick to it I think. You could do it with one function expression using `array_reduce`, or could simply use a `foreach` loop:

```
$input = [
    [
        'zoomlevel'=> 1,
        'metric_cnt_1'=> 1
    ], [
        'zoomlevel'=> 4,
        'metric_cnt_1'=> 1
    ], [
        'zoomlevel'=> 6,
        'metric_cnt_1'=> 2
    ]
];

$expected = [
    1 => 1,
    4 => 1,
    6 => 2
];

$result = array_reduce($input, function ($result, $record) {
    $key = $record['zoomlevel'];
    $value = $record['metric_cnt_1'];
    $result[$key] = $value;
    return $result;
}, []);

var_dump(assert($result == $expected));

$result2 = [];
foreach ($input as $record) {
    $key = $record['zoomlevel'];
    $value = $record['metric_cnt_1'];
    $result2[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump(assert($result2 == $expected));
```

I always try to avoid using generic `foreach` loops where possible, but that's just personal preference. Usually using the purposeful array higher-order functions are clearer as to what the intention is. I also don't like hand-cranking the construction of an array if I can avoid it. I think there's not much in it, in this case.

---

Another, possibly better answer would be to just get the data in the format you need it in in the first place:

```
$connection = new \PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=scratch", "scratch", "scratch");

$result = $connection->query('
    select district_id as zoomlevel, count(*) as metric_cnt_1
    from members
    group by district_id
')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP | \PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | \PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

$expected = [
    1 => 1,
    4 => 1,
    6 => 2
];

var_dump(assert($result == $expected));
```

Comment: Thanks it works. @Adam, I am studying your solution to understand how it works.

Comment: @LakmalPremaratne see my update too. That might be a better approach, depending on whether you need the original data for something else as well.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function will do this for you:

```
$result = array_column($input, 'metric_cnt_1', 'zoomlevel');
```

Comment: Ooh I didnae know about the `index_key` parameter of that! Nice one. Better than my answer (except perhaps the PDO-centric one)

Comment: The `index_key` argument does make `array_column()` a lot more powerful